# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls' error while using checkIn command

Tags: visual-studio-2008, checkin

I have VS2008 connected to TFS2012. I am trying to CheckIn from command line. But when i run tf checkIn this error occuring

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Control
s, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of
its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls dll in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies. I have tried to run command for different workspaces. Can anyone please tell me what is the cause for the error and what is the solution?

Comment: I'm guessing because TFS 2012 has this policy built in, your server is now using Version 11.0 of the policy assembly. I don't know how to resolve this though. But it might give you something to look at.

Comment: I can't see anything about CheckIn policy in the error. We also have some users using VS2008 and TFS2012 and they do not have any problem with Comment policy, after installing TFS 2008 Power Tools, because the name didn't changed and it doesn't care for version.
Did you used the /noprompt argument? I'm wondering why the checkin is looking for the Controls dll. Maybe a conflict occurs and it tries to open a merge window. Does the checkin work in VS on this machine?

Comment: Ya checkin works fine in VS.And i have not used /noprompt

Comment: I just found out the reason.I had copied tf.exe to my workspace folder for checkin. It seems tf.exe searching for dll files in current directory instead of Visual studio installation directory. checkIn working fine if I copy required dll files to workspace folder. But i cant copy dll files to all workspaces.What to do?